# Add value between column using sed/awk based on matching value at certain column

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a log files with many records. All line of rows and columns have same format. I want to use sed to match value in certain column and adding new value in between column. As an example, a log like this :

```
    2014.3.17 23:57:11 127.0.0.3 10.21.31.141 http://vcs2.msg.yahoo.com/capacity *DENIED* Banned site: msg.yahoo.com GET 0 0  3 403 - working_time content3 -
```

My command will search the log for msg.yahoo.com (column 9th) and if match it will add value (Social Media) between column 12 and 13. As intended output :

```
    2014.3.17 23:57:11 127.0.0.3 10.21.31.141 http://vcs2.msg.yahoo.com/capacity *DENIED* Banned site: msg.yahoo.com GET 0 0 Social Media 3 403 - working_time content3 -
```

My awk code only put Social Media between column 12 and 13 :

```
    awk -v column=12 -v value="Social Media" '
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = " ";
}
{
    for ( i = NF + 1; i > column; i-- ) {
        $i = $(i-1);
    }
    $i = value;
    print $0;
}
' access3.log
```

but it need to find msg.yahoo.com in column 9 before add value. Its like this, if column
9 = msg.yahoo.com, put Social Media after column 12 or between 12 and 13 column.

Answer (score 1):

Workable but ugly is sed (as things so often are):

```
sed '/\([^ ]* \)\{8\}msg\.yahoo\.com/s/\(\([^ ]* \)\{12\}\)/\1Social Media /' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix for awk

```
awk '$9=="msg.yahoo.com"{$(NF-6)=$(NF-6) " Social Media"}1' access3.log
```

#### Explanation

- `$9=="msg.yahoo.com"` only target on the line which msg.yahoo.com in column 9
- `$(NF-6)=$(NF-6) " Social Media"` column (NF-6) is the reverse column 6 from end, and replace with a new value.
- `1` just means true and print.

Comment: Thanks, its work. How about some explanation, i only understand the first part column 9 = msg.yahoo.com.

Comment: Added the explanation.Cheers